# How to use $In operatore Query builder symfony2+MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Hi I have following query I want to fetch data by checking a particular Id exists inside array (stored as collection)in mongoDb as follows:
    //Vouchers collection:

```
 "byLedgers": [
 [
   "57a578b7518459d1008b4567",
   "57a30cd25184590a018b4567"
    ]
 ]
So I am running query in my repository as following:
$getAllVouchers =     $dm->createQueryBuilder('EduAccountBundle:VoucherGeneration');
        $getAllVouchers->field('isDeleted')->Equals(false);
        $getAllVouchers->addOr($getAllVouchers->expr()->field('byLedgers')->Equals($id)); //Here how to use $in instead Equals
        $getAllVouchers->addAnd($getAllVouchers->expr()->field('financialYear')->Equals($currentFinancialYear));
$resultTo = $getAllVouchers->getQuery()->execute();
```

I am getting 0 result. I need to use $in instead Equals. but not sure how to use it. Please help
Thanks in advance